# Is there a GNU C compiler option that generate floating point programs that run faster but less precise than the default setting?

Tags: c++, c, performance, floating-point, precision

I have been looking for an option of GNU C so that my floating point programs can be generated to code that runs faster although less precise, than the code generated by the default gnu setting.

Say I have a program my_fp_prog.c

```
double sqrt_two(return sqrt(2));
```

While the precise answer should be 1.414...., I only need the answer 1.4 or even 1.5 or 1.3 is ok for me, but I need a faster program. Of course, we case use a cheaper sqrt algorithm yet what I am seeking is a compiler option that does the job. Hopefully such an option exists.

Comment: What about hard-coding the square root of two in a constant? I know it sounds devilish at first, but you'll soon realize that only quiche eaters avoid magic constants.

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/FloatingPointMath

Comment: I've no idea why my comment was deleted. I asked whether `double fastsqrt(double x) { return 0; }` would be acceptable. The point being that one simply has to define what this function should be. One cannot say `1.3` is OK and call that a specification.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan No idea who flagged and/or deleted it and why, but probably nobody got your hidden point. It looked like a perfect example of "not constructive". (Or the deleter didn´t care about your point, because we can understand what OP means without a formal specification)

Comment: @deviant If you can understand that please tell me the range of acceptable values for `sqrt(2)`.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Please just stop. There is no point in discussing this.

Comment: @deviantfan I'll take that as a sign that the spec is not clear

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Sigh. Fine. Not what you´ve in mind, but: The question clearly states that OP knows he can use a different function, but *he wants a GNU C compiler option instead* => no code changes => As long you can´t say a GNU C compiler option to replace every float calculation with 0 or to make it even less precise, it´s irrelevant if a constant 0 is precise enough or not.

Comment: And "less precise" here means "higher difference between correct and calculated result allowed. Opposite for "more precise". You can take any max. difference >0 you like, it won´t change the answer => There is no need to specify a specific precision at all, as long the max. difference isn´t 0 (result of fully capable calculation), everything is fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From GCC's man page:

> **`-ffast-math`**
>
> Sets `-fno-math-errno`, `-funsafe-math-optimizations`, `-ffinite-math-only`, `-fno-rounding-math`, `-fno-signaling-nans` and `-fcx-limited-range`.
>
> This option causes the preprocessor macro `__FAST_MATH__` to be defined.
>
> This option is not turned on by any `-O` option besides `-Ofast` since it can result in incorrect output for programs that depend on an exact implementation of IEEE or ISO rules/specifications for math functions. It may, however, yield faster code for programs that do not require the guarantees of these specifications.

Comment: While this is factually correct, I doubt it will help as much as OP wants. Using explicit approximations is likely to perform better and doesn't introduce potential bugs outside the locality where you want to use fast approximations.

Comment: @R.. The OP is asking how to make a constant faster. Nothing is going to help them as much as they want.

Comment: @PascalCuoq: Well yes, but I would hope that's just a poor statement of the problem and not the actual code...